# tableView.reloadData() then fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift, reloaddata, removeall

```
var Array = [String]()  

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.func), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func(){
    Array.removeAll()
    ...
    for value in data{
        ...
        Array.append(string_value)
        ...
    }
    ...
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

then

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCel{

      cell.label.text = Array[indexPath.row]
      return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.Array.count
}
```

and when an update (tableView.reloadData()) -> fatal error:

> Index out of range

tell me what my mistake?

Comment: can you show us your "numberOfRowInSection" method ?

Comment: You are strongly discouraged from using a Swift type (`Array`) as a variable name

Comment: make sure 'numberOfRowsInSection' returns 'Array.count'

Comment: Array name for example

Comment: scrolling update tableView and Ok! error there tableView.reloadData()

Comment: @NathanLevitt 'numberOfRowsInSection' returns 'Array.count' yes

Comment: Can you add the other tableView methods please

Comment: if "Array.removeAll()" delete, reloadData() no Error